# How would I useState to get the last updated user input in order to generate a URL

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

I believe that so far I have set up the input tags that the user will input the relevant things needed in order for me to pull out a picture from the NASA API. I don't think that the state that I have are getting the last inputted information and printing out to the console the URL from the user input. I think the problem may be with how I use state but I don't have an idea about how to do it even after I read the docs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const getCamera = (c) => {
  const inputedCamera = c.target.value;
  console.log(inputedCamera);
}

const getRover = (r) => {
  const inputedRover = r.target.value;
  console.log(inputedRover)
}

const getDate = (d) => {
  const inputedDate = d.target.value;
  console.log(inputedDate);
}
const constructURL = (camera, rover, date) => {
  const userURL = "https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/" + rover + "/photos?earth_date=" + date + "&camera=" + camera + "&api_key=DEMO_KEY";
  console.log(userURL)
}

const App = () => {

  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState("");
  const [camera, setCamera] = useState("");
  const [rover, setRover] = useState("");
  const [date, setDate] = useState("");

  const gettingInfo = () => {
    fetch(constructURL(camera, rover, date))
    .then((response) => {setPhotos(response.json()['photos'])}) //sets values for photos 
    .catch(() => console.log("Fetch Failed")) 

  }; 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div id='container'>
          <div>
            <input type="text" id="date-picker" name="date-picker" placeholder="Enter a date" onChange={getDate}></input>
            <input type="text" id="rover" name="rover" placeholder="Enter a rover" onChange={getRover}></input>
            <input type="text" id="camera" name="camera" placeholder="Enter a camera" onChange={getCamera}></input>
          </div>
          <button onClick={console.log(gettingInfo)}>URL generator</button>
        </div>
      </header>

      <body>
      </body>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `value` attribute inside the `input` tag. Use:

```
<input type="text" id="rover" name="rover" value={rover} placeholder="Enter a rover" onChange={getRover}></input>
```

I would also recommend that you move your methods i.e. getCamera, getRover, getDate inside the App function.

There's also a better approach by using only one state with all your attributes and replacing all the methods with only one method and then using `value={state.rover}` or whatever the name of that particular field is. It goes something like this:

```
const onInputChange = (event) => {
  [event.target.name]: event.target.value
}
```

then using it like this: `onChange={onInputChange}`